# How to store variable inside an array unity?

Tags: unity

I was wondering how I can store these `anims` inside an array, because, the start function will be fired one time. I would like to be able to call these `Animators` more then one time.

```
    public Animator anim0;
    public Animator anim25;
    public Animator anim50;
    public Animator anim75;
    public Animator anim100;

void Start () {

        anim0 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire0").GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim25 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire25").GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim50 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire50").GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim75 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire75").GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim100 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire100").GetComponent<Animator>();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
Animator[] anims = new Animator[number_of_animators];

anims[0] = anim0;
...
```

if you mean to have an array editable inside the editor you can declare it as public and you will specify inside the editor its size and you will be able to drag and drop elements into it

just like this:

```
public Animator[] anims;
```

this is to be declared just as variable. No need to initialize inside Start()

then to check which animation is being played just declare

```
AnimationInfo[] animPlayed;
```

and when it is needed call

```
animPlayed = you_animator.GetCurrentAnimationClipState (0);
```

which returns the first animation clip being played (because you may have more concurrent animation)

Comment: I think I will give it a try. To make the animators public, just set `public` before the first line? And should I also make a foreach loop to create the lines like: `anim0 = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Campfire0").GetComponent<Animator>();` or is it just `anims[0] = anim0;`, `anims[25] = anim25;`?

Comment: see my edit. I added how you could have an array that can be modified in the editor

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Should I set it inside the Start function or above? And what should I set in `number_of_animators`?

Comment: I edited again. Please consider editing your quesiton with your other question

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I am quit new to Unity. But does `number_of_animators` exactly mean? Should I insert a number instead of it or create a variable? @Leggy7

Comment: I think you are confusing Animations with Animators. At this point I suggest you to watch Unity tutorial for this purpose :)